# How to write an efficient Go implementation of built-in function copy?

Tags: go

I have two byte buffers `var a,b []byte`, I am looking for a replacement for Go's built-in copy function to copy from one byte buffer to the other, preferably pure Go implementation and efficiency is important.

The reason is that `copy` reliably crashes my program due to `unexpected fault address`, therefore I would like to experiment with a non-native `copy()` replacement to find out if the crash was caused by my program logics or not.

Comment: Looks like a  bug in the runtime. Could you attempt to reduce your code to the smallest possible piece that still exhibits the problem?

Comment: thanks @FUZxxl after some debugging, I found that a mistake in my buffer management caused copy to segfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of debugging, use something like this:

```
func myCopy (a, b []byte) int {
    var length int

    if (len(a) < len(b)) {
        length = len(a)
    } else {
        length = len(b)
    }

   for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
        a[i] = b[i]
   }

   return length
}
```